# Referencing an external resource in a LESS file using WebPack

Tags: css, less, webpack

I need to `@import` an externally managed URL from LESS and am using WebPack but am unable to figure out how to do so.

Specifically, I need to `@import` a few URLs from myfonts.net in order to work with their licensing.

I am essentially doing the following:

`@import url("//myfonts.net");`

But WebPack is looking for the file locally instead of importing the URL.

I believe the issue is with `css-loader` trying to resolve the file locally but I'm unsure how to indicate to `css-loader` to not resolve the URL at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude files from loader config:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, exclude: /^(https?:)?\/\//, loader: 'style!css'},
```